# C# Parallel.Foreach that is not peforming action on all items in list

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

```
    public static void RemoveAllNetworkPrinters()
    {
        ManagementScope oManagementScope = new ManagementScope(ManagementPath.DefaultPath);
        oManagementScope.Connect();

        SelectQuery oSelectQuery = new SelectQuery();
        oSelectQuery.QueryString = @"SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer WHERE ServerName IS NOT NULL";

        using (ManagementObjectSearcher oObjectSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(oManagementScope, oSelectQuery))
        {
            using (ManagementObjectCollection oObjectCollection = oObjectSearcher.Get())
            {
                if (oObjectCollection.Count != 0)
                {
                    foreach (ManagementObject oItem in oObjectCollection)
                    {
                        oItem.Delete();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void RemoveAllNetworkPrintersParallel()
    {
        ManagementScope oManagementScope = new ManagementScope(ManagementPath.DefaultPath);
        oManagementScope.Connect();

        SelectQuery oSelectQuery = new SelectQuery();
        oSelectQuery.QueryString = @"SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer WHERE ServerName IS NOT NULL";

        using (ManagementObjectSearcher oObjectSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(oManagementScope, oSelectQuery))
        {
            using (ManagementObjectCollection oObjectCollection = oObjectSearcher.Get())
            {
                if (oObjectCollection.Count != 0)
                {
                    Parallel.ForEach(oObjectCollection.OfType<ManagementObject>().ToList(), oItem =>
                    {
                        oItem.Delete();
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a question in reference to the Parallel.Foreach in c#. I have been testing with and see something odd in example I am providing for testing purposes. When I perform the non parallel version of this function it works fine but when I do a parallel version anywhere between 1-2 items will not process in the list I am cycling through. I have read the msdn documentation but must be missing something here. I know you can't guarantee the order items will be processed but thought it was guaranteed all items would be processed in the list? Any help in understanding or what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Had you tried to debug/trace it? Why do you think that not all items processed?

Comment: When I add the same 40 printers to workstation before running there are always 1-2 items that are left behind when running parallel version. The items left behind are random and not the same. If I run the parallel version a second time after items are left remaining it removes the 1-2 items left.

Comment: What's the action of `oItem.Delete();`? You should not remove items from a collection inside an interator of that collection

Comment: You need to log/trace your ```item.Delete``` action, since I think that problem is there, not in parralel library. Even more, look, in foreach you iterating ```oObjectCollection```, in parallel, ```oObjectCollection.OfType<ManagementObject>().ToList()``` - it is not same collections, so problem could be there as well

Comment: oItem.Delete removes the printer from  the local workstation and does not affect list.

Comment: Probably your code for Delete is not thread safe so you get the error. When using parallel you should make everything immutable or use patterns that are thread safe.

Comment: When I add a Thread.Sleep(1000) before the oItem.Delete(); I cannot replicate the error.

Comment: You need to log/trace your item.Delete action, since I think that problem is there, not in parralel library. Even more, look, in foreach you iterating oObjectCollection, in parallel, oObjectCollection.OfType<ManagementObject>().ToList() - it is not same collections, so problem could be there as well. Unsure what you mean by this? I have to use as ManagementObjectCollection uses the non generic Ienumerable. I get same behavior if I do oObjectCollection.Cast<ManagementObject>()

Comment: ```When I add a Thread.Sleep(1000)``` - I guess that ```oItem.Delete();``` is not thread safe. You proved it by adding ```Thread.Sleep()``` which gives time to finish previous  ```oItem.Delete();``` before call next  ```oItem.Delete();```

Comment: @Filip Cordas here is link on documentation for Delete method. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a2k71172(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobject(v=vs.110).aspx) ```Any public static ( Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.``` And ```oItem.Delete()``` - instance member.

Comment: @tym32167 Thanks for clarifying. Is there an easy way to make thread safe? When I do lock (oItem){oItem.Delete();}; I still get same issue?

Comment: Its not thread safe, so you shouldnt use in from different threads. Its not make sense to use lock inside parralel.foreach, because it will be slower than ordinal foreach.

Comment: btw, your ```lock``` is not working because each time you locking different object. Use same object for all ```lock``` stuff there if you really need this.

Comment: Got it. Thanks I wouldn't use but was curious for future items I may look at. Thanks again.

Comment: Added as answer just to make next reader life easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, `ManagementObject.Delete()` is not thread safe operation, so you should not use it from different threads 
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobject(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Any public static ( Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

But if you really need to do this and you want to use `lock` there, you can do smthg like this

```
var lockObject = new Object();

Parallel.ForEach(/*.....*/, item =>
{
    lock (lockObject)
    {
        // do your magic here
    }
});
```

BUT as I said **its is not make sense to use this code since it will be slower that ordinal foreach**.

So, my recommendation - use just foreach.

Comment: Thanks again. Appreciate the help, explanation, and code.